# Subdomain pages not displayed

Tags: php, subdomain

I have hard times figuring out Why pages in my subdomains do not display (instead it displays the English page in the app directory).

I have the following subdomains for each language with index php file in it. I have a few subdomains - per attached picture

The language links should open relevant index pages and they don't - ref https://reverd.com/app/

I noticed that I have to change in my config file the previous public_html for my html pages are now in the root, but it didn't work either:

```
$http_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) // document root directory
    $ROOT_DIR = $_SERVER['HOME'] . '/public_html';
else
{
    if (in_array($http_host, $sub_domains))
        $ROOT_DIR = str_replace($http_host, 'public_html', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    else
        $ROOT_DIR = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

Thanks,

[image: subdomain links]

Comment: So how did you setup these subdomains in your Apache config? Show us!

Comment: I used the standard subdomain creation feature of IONOS (the hosting) sorry cannot attach a screenshot here.

Comment: Then this morning I saw that I have to connect each subdomain to my Webspace and I did - still don't see the subdomain pages...

Comment: Hmm it might work. I've at least one subdomain working so far... one step closer... will keep you posted.

Comment: Yes, problem solved. On IONOS hosting once subdomains are created each subdomain is to be connected to the proper folder. That's it.